# "package org.junit does not exist" when running first time

Tags: git, maven, junit, junit5

I am working on a little schoolproject. Whenever I get my code from Git, the following errors appear when running it for the first time:

```
"package org.junit does not exist" 
"package org.junit.runners does not exist"
"cannot find symbol"
```

When I run the project for a second time, everything works as expected. This is very annoying because I want to run the project in Jenkins with source code import from Git so it has to work the first time.

I checked my build path in Eclipse, but JUnit5 is included from the start. 
I don't know if something is wrong with my pom, everything seems fine as far as my knowledge goes.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Selenium dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>all</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>13</source>
                <target>13</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: First remove the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` from maven-surefire-plugin configuration. Upgrade to 2.22.2 at least furthermore change the imports in your code cause it has to be `org.junit.jupiter.api.test` etc. and junit runners do not exist anymore in JUnit Jupiter . Remove the dependency `maven-surefire-report-plugin` ...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my own problem.

After a Merge a collegue added some tests, configured in an older version of JUnit.  That's why it failed. After adding JUnit 4 to my POM my problem was solved. Updating the tests to the JUnit 5n should also solve the problem.